# Centering of the model in Blender 3.0.1

Tags: modeling

This is a part of video from tutorial I following:

[image]

How do I make the cross center with propeller of plane? I have it miscentered like this: [image]

I need it for a part in red circle to center like this: [image]

Comment: Adjust "Offset Y" to move the image up or down.  Hold the shift key to make it work slowly.

Comment: @MartyFouts I would add to turn on snapping, or possibly better, go into edit mode on the plane and use the Shift+C pie menu to move the 3D cursor onto the propeller tip, then go back to object mode and use the same pie menu to move the image to the 3D cursor.