# Misaligned part of the model

Tags: modeling

I need this part in yellow circle: [image]

To be like this: [image]

But when it is placed like that, this is happening: [image]

I need it to be like this:

[image]

Why is this non-alignment happening and how to fix this?
I am following this youtube tutorial: Blender Day 6- Modeling Aircraft - Introduction to Blender/ Beginners Series

Comment: It looks like you're using more than one reference image - one or the X and Y axis, respectively - is it possible they are not correctly aligned/placed?

Comment: I adjusted "Offset Y" as this is what they advised me to do here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263163/centering-of-the-model-in-blender-3-0-1 Maybe is that problem?

Comment: It's possible... there are a lot of things to consider - are the images meant as reference images - are they meant to have the same scale and proportions? If they are, that should be a relatively easy matter of adjusting the vertical offset of one of the images. If they are of different scale, then you might be in for a bunch of tedious manual scaling/aligning.